# Ошибка: TypeError: gcd()missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Помогите решить проблему, не знаю с чем связана ошибка

```
from decimal import Decimal 
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.title('RSA')
# Variables for checkboxes/listbox
TextVar  = StringVar(value=1111)
QVar = StringVar(value=25)
PVar = IntVar(value=37)
letterVar = IntVar()
specialVar = IntVar()
digitalVar = IntVar()
enChar = StringVar()
# Checkboxes
LabelClose = Label(window, width=15, text="Закрытый ключ").grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=E)
LabelClose1 = Label(window, text="")
LabelClose1.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=E)
labelOpen = Label(window, text="Открытый ключ").grid(row=2, column=3)
LabelOpen1 = Label(window, text="")
LabelOpen1.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=E)
LabelEncr = Label(window, width=15, text="Зашифрованный текст").grid(row=4, column=3, sticky=E)
LabelEncr1 = Label(window, text="")
LabelEncr1.grid(row=5, column=3, sticky=E)
LabelDecr = Label(window, width=15, text="Дешифрованный текст").grid(row=6, column=3, sticky=E)
LabelDecr1 = Label(window, text="")
LabelDecr1.grid(row=7, column=3, sticky=E)


# Button
button = Button(window, text="Начать", width=12)
button.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky=E)
# Labels

labelText= Label(window, text="Введите текст:").grid(row=4, column=0)
labelP = Label(window, text="Введите P:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
labelQ = Label(window, text="Введите Q:").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

# Entry
entryP = Entry(window, width=10, textvariable=PVar).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W+E)
entryQ = Entry(window, width=22, textvariable=QVar).grid(row=3, column=0)
entryText= Entry(window, width=22, textvariable=TextVar).grid(row=5, column=0)


def gcd(a,b): 
    if b==0: 
        return a 
    else: 
        return gcd(b,a%b) 
    p = PVar.get()
    q = QVar.get()
    no = TextVar.get()
    n = int(p)*int(q) 
    t = (int(p)-1)*(int(q)-1) 
    e = 1
    for e in range(2,t): 
        if gcd(e,t)== 1: 
            break


    for i in range(1,10): 
        x = 1 + i*t 
        if x % e == 0: 
            d = int(x/e) 
            break
    ctt = Decimal(0) 
    ctt = pow(int(no),int(e)) 
    print(ctt)
    ct = int(ctt) % int(n) 

    dtt = Decimal(0) 
    dtt = pow(ct,d) 
    dt = int(dtt) % int(n) 
    LabelClose1['text'] = (str(e)+str(n))
    LabelOpen1['text'] = (str(d)+str(n))
    LabelEncr1['text'] = (str(ct))
    LabelDecr1['text'] = (str(dt))

    # print('n = '+str(n)+' e = '+str(e)+' t = '+str(t)+' d = '+str(d)+' cipher text = '+str(ct)+' decrypted text = '+str(dt)) 
    # print('Открытый ключ = {' +str(e)+ ', ' +str(n)+ '}')
    # print('Закрытый ключ = {' +str(d)+ ', ' +str(n)+ '}')
    # print('Зашифрованный текст = '+str(ct))



button.bind('<Button-1>',gcd)
window.geometry("400x250")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: а в какой строке ошибка то?

Comment: при нажатии на кнопку, пишет ошибку  File "C:\Users\38050\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: gcd() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

Comment: у вас все нормально работает и считает?

Comment: нет, с tkinter я не работал, но я вижу, что у вас gcd принимает два аргумента, а ошибка в том, что получает только один, и ждет b

Comment: может .bind() передает только 1 аргумент, честно не скажу

Answer (score 2):

У вас здесь не одна ошибка.

Во-первых, ваша функция gcd написана так, что он должна принимать два аргумента - a и b.
Но вы привязываете эту функцию к событию нажатия на кнопку. Очевидно, кнопка ни откуда не знает, что в эту функцию нужно передавать какие-то a и b. На самом деле, кнопка при нажатии всегда передаёт привязанной функции только один аргумент, который содержит разную информацию о самом нажатии.

Во-вторых, у вас функция gcd в любом случае завершит свою работу либо после строчек

```
if b==0: 
    return a
```

либо после строчек

```
else: 
    return gcd(b,a%b)
```

А у вас в этой функции ещё дальше много понаписано, и оно никогда не выполнится.

То есть вам все эти последующие строчки нужно вынести в отдельную функцию, которая и будет привязана к кнопке.

```
from decimal import Decimal
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.title('RSA')
# Variables for checkboxes/listbox
TextVar = StringVar(value=1111)
QVar = StringVar(value=25)
PVar = IntVar(value=37)
letterVar = IntVar()
specialVar = IntVar()
digitalVar = IntVar()
enChar = StringVar()
# Checkboxes
LabelClose = Label(window, width=15, text="Закрытый ключ").grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=E)
LabelClose1 = Label(window, text="")
LabelClose1.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=E)
labelOpen = Label(window, text="Открытый ключ").grid(row=2, column=3)
LabelOpen1 = Label(window, text="")
LabelOpen1.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=E)
LabelEncr = Label(window, width=15, text="Зашифрованный текст").grid(row=4, column=3, sticky=E)
LabelEncr1 = Label(window, text="")
LabelEncr1.grid(row=5, column=3, sticky=E)
LabelDecr = Label(window, width=15, text="Дешифрованный текст").grid(row=6, column=3, sticky=E)
LabelDecr1 = Label(window, text="")
LabelDecr1.grid(row=7, column=3, sticky=E)


# Button
button = Button(window, text="Начать", width=12)
button.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky=E)
# Labels

labelText= Label(window, text="Введите текст:").grid(row=4, column=0)
labelP = Label(window, text="Введите P:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
labelQ = Label(window, text="Введите Q:").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

# Entry
entryP = Entry(window, width=10, textvariable=PVar).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W+E)
entryQ = Entry(window, width=22, textvariable=QVar).grid(row=3, column=0)
entryText= Entry(window, width=22, textvariable=TextVar).grid(row=5, column=0)


def gcd(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return gcd(b, a%b)


def calculate(_):
    p = PVar.get()
    q = QVar.get()
    no = TextVar.get()
    n = int(p)*int(q)
    t = (int(p)-1)*(int(q)-1)
    e = 1
    for e in range(2,t):
        if gcd(e,t)== 1:
            break

    for i in range(1,10):
        x = 1 + i*t
        if x % e == 0:
            d = int(x/e)
            break
    ctt = Decimal(0)
    ctt = pow(int(no),int(e))
    print(ctt)
    ct = int(ctt) % int(n)

    dtt = Decimal(0)
    dtt = pow(ct,d)
    dt = int(dtt) % int(n)
    LabelClose1['text'] = (str(e)+str(n))
    LabelOpen1['text'] = (str(d)+str(n))
    LabelEncr1['text'] = (str(ct))
    LabelDecr1['text'] = (str(dt))

    # print('n = '+str(n)+' e = '+str(e)+' t = '+str(t)+' d = '+str(d)+' cipher text = '+str(ct)+' decrypted text = '+str(dt))
    # print('Открытый ключ = {' +str(e)+ ', ' +str(n)+ '}')
    # print('Закрытый ключ = {' +str(d)+ ', ' +str(n)+ '}')
    # print('Зашифрованный текст = '+str(ct))

button.bind('<Button-1>', calculate)  # !!! Обратите внимание на эту строку !!!
window.geometry("400x250")

window.mainloop()
```

В таком виде код не выдаёт ошибки и что-то считает. Не знаю уж, насколько верно, лень было вникать глубже.
Но даже беглый взгляд обнаруживает пару подозрительных моментов.

Например:

```
ctt = Decimal(0)            # Эта строчка бессмысленна и ни на что не влияет
                            # Так как в следующей строчке
                            # переменная ctt пересоздаётся
ctt = pow(int(no),int(e))
print(ctt)
ct = int(ctt) % int(n)

dtt = Decimal(0)            # И здесь то же самое
dtt = pow(ct,d)
dt = int(dtt) % int(n)
```